# Replace text in a WIX property

Tags: wix

Say I have existing property [A] that contains the value:

"Folder1/Folder2"

But in order to make it into a valid path, I need it to be:

"Folder1\Folder2"  *note the slash changed direction

How can do this is WIX?

Comment: I'd be surprised if windows cared about whack vs stroke. Far as I know, either is accepted for paths on win7 or better.

Comment: That's true, but WIX will only accept "/" for virtual directories in IIS and will only accept "\" for file paths (at least within a SetTargetPath action).

Answer (score 0):

You can make  loop`foreach` char in that property replace / with \ .

Forgot to say that you will need custom action for that.After the value is changed just set it :

```
session["YOURWIXPROPERTY"] = resultFromLoop ;
```